# Hibernate 4 calls setBinaryStream that is not supported in c3p0

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

Hibernate 4 uses jdbc4, were the signature of method setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, int) was changed to setBinaryStream(int, InputStream, **long**). C3P0 does not support this new method.

So calling saveOrUpdate(myObjWithBlob) results

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy75.setBinaryStream(Unknown Source)
```

So what can i do now?

1) Do not use c3p0. DHCP, BoneCP or no conntection pool at all. - is not really the option i want.

2) Somehow make hibernate avoid calling this new method? Is ist possible?

3) Switching back to hibernate 3 - is also not really good for me.

Comment: I don't believe #2 is possible.  As for #1, there are also native connection pools in Tomcat 7 and JBoss 7 if you are using either of those web servers.

Comment: It does appear that at one point in time Hibernate 4 was supposed to support JDBC 3, but I haven't been able to figure out how one would do that: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JDBC4Support

Comment: Also, it appears you can avoid this method if you avoid blobs.  Not sure if that is an option.

Comment: Last, but not least, you can compile C3P0 yourself as suggested here: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7801

Comment: hm...it seems to be strange that default connection pool of hibernate breaks such essential thing as saveOrUpdate...hope it will be fixed in future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please upgrade to c3p0 0.9.2-pre8 (or wait a few days for 0.9.2 final). This issue has been resolved in recent releases of the library.

**Update:** c3p0-0.9.2 is now a release. it does resolve this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, the upgrade to 0.9.2 saved my day ;)