# Error with serialversionUID mismatch after c3p0 jar upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, jndi, jtds

The application I was working on uses spring and hibernate 3 earlier. I have upgraded the application to spring 4.1.6 and hibernate 4.3.0. The application was up and running but an exception is thrown when hibernate calls setBinaryStream method of c3p0(c3p0 version 0.9.1.2) just as it is mentioned in this post :

[Hibernate 4 calls setBinaryStream that is not supported in c3p0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771399/hibernate-4-calls-setbinarystream-that-is-not-supported-in-c3p0)

As advised in the answer I have updated the c3p0 version.The following exception occured when I changed the c3p0 version to 0.9.2.1 :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiCoreBankDataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dataSourceContext-fs.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected exception [Root exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7806429541739165290, local class serialVersionUID = -7086951306718003710]; remaining name '"jdbc/cored"'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:802)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: unexpected exception [Root exception is java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7806429541739165290, local class serialVersionUID = -7086951306718003710]; remaining name '"jdbc/corebank"'
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.generateNamingException(FSContext.java:806)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:149)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.FSContext.lookup(FSContext.java:127)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7806429541739165290, local class serialVersionUID = -7086951306718003710
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1885)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at com.mchange.v2.ser.SerializableUtils.deserializeFromByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:144)
    at com.mchange.v2.ser.SerializableUtils.fromByteArray(SerializableUtils.java:123)
    at com.mchange.v2.naming.JavaBeanObjectFactory.createPropertyMap(JavaBeanObjectFactory.java:110)
    at com.mchange.v2.naming.JavaBeanObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(JavaBeanObjectFactory.java:71)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContext.lookup(RefFSContext.java:146)
    ... 73 more
```

Following is the xml configuration related to the incident :

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${jndi.contextFactory}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${jndi.providerUrl}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="targetDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate"/>
     <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/cored" />
    </bean>
```

I haven't touched the jtds and jndi jars. Is it because they are not compatible? But given that there is a serialversionUID mismatch, I believe that there is a different version of the class `WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource` somewhere which I couldn't figure out as I have searched the whole project.

In the props for jndi template I am loading the jndi context from filesystem :

```
<prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop>
<prop key="java.naming.provider.url">file:d:/jndi-support/jdbc</prop>
```

Below is the jndi support folder. Here bindings are generated using the fsjndibinder.jar. fsjndibinder.jar contains all the dependencies packaged inside it. i.e the old c3p0 09.1.2, jtds, jndi libraries are packaged. Was this causing the serialversionUID issue? Or was it the bindings file that is generated using the old libraries packaged in fsjndibinder.jar causing it? If so it means that the bindings file is a serialized version of the `WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource` class or it contains the serialversionUID to match with that in my project? I don't have experience with jndi bindings and how it associates with pooling.

[image]

Edit : It was indeed a binding issue as i have generated the binding files with new libraries but forgot to move on of the bindings file generated to the patch from where it is being read by the application. The application now able to connect now, but I am facing the same issue but with jtds library which I guess is incompatible with the new version of c3p0 (v0.9.2.1). Current jtds version is 1.2.2.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/JtdsPreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V is abstract
```

I have changed the JTDS jar to v1.3.1 and now the following exception is throw :

```
2021-09-19 13:21:00,552 [main] WARN  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement  - Exception on close of inner statement.
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.checkOpen(TdsCore.java:481)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.clearResponseQueue(TdsCore.java:767)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.reset(JtdsStatement.java:722)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.close(JtdsStatement.java:966)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.close(NewProxyStatement.java:867)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.closeStatement(JdbcUtils.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:412)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:440)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.dao.impl.RubyDaoHelperImpl.executeCommand(RubyDaoHelperImpl.java:173)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.dao.impl.RubyDaoHelperImpl.executeSql(RubyDaoHelperImpl.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor125.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:170)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.ReflectionCallback.invokeMethod0(ReflectionCallback.java:101)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.AbstractCallback.invokeMethod(AbstractCallback.java:114)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.AbstractCallback.execute(AbstractCallback.java:181)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CallbackMethod.call(CallbackMethod.java:69)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call0(RubyModule.java:672)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call(RubyModule.java:633)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitCallNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:453)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNode.accept(CallNode.java:62)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitDAsgnNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:603)
    at org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.accept(DAsgnNode.java:58)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.EvaluateMethod.call(EvaluateMethod.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.yield(ThreadContext.java:273)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.yield(Ruby.java:323)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:107)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:102)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.ProcMethod.call(ProcMethod.java:60)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call0(RubyModule.java:672)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call(RubyModule.java:633)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitCallNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:453)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNode.accept(CallNode.java:62)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.RubyObject.eval(RubyObject.java:407)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call0(RubyModule.java:672)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call(RubyModule.java:633)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitFCallNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:823)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallNode.accept(FCallNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.RubyObject.eval(RubyObject.java:407)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:106)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call0(RubyModule.java:672)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call(RubyModule.java:633)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitCallNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:453)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNode.accept(CallNode.java:62)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitRescueNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1237)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.accept(RescueNode.java:61)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBeginNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:324)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.accept(BeginNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.EvaluateMethod.call(EvaluateMethod.java:71)
    at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.yield(ThreadContext.java:273)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.yield(Ruby.java:323)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.yield(Ruby.java:319)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:812)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.ReflectionCallback.invokeMethod0(ReflectionCallback.java:101)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.AbstractCallback.invokeMethod(AbstractCallback.java:114)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callback.AbstractCallback.execute(AbstractCallback.java:181)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CallbackMethod.call(CallbackMethod.java:69)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call0(RubyModule.java:672)
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.call(RubyModule.java:633)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitCallNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:453)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNode.accept(CallNode.java:62)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitIterNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:975)
    at org.jruby.ast.IterNode.accept(IterNode.java:61)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBeginNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:324)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.accept(BeginNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitNewlineNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:1068)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.accept(NewlineNode.java:68)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.visitBlockNode(EvaluateVisitor.java:340)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.accept(BlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.EvaluateVisitor.eval(EvaluateVisitor.java:223)
    at org.jruby.runtime.ThreadContext.eval(ThreadContext.java:126)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.eval(Ruby.java:180)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.evalScript(Ruby.java:176)
    at org.jruby.javasupport.bsf.JRubyEngine.exec(JRubyEngine.java:102)
    at org.apache.bsf.BSFManager$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.bsf.BSFManager.exec(Unknown Source)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.RubyScriptRunner.rubyExec(RubyScriptRunner.java:60)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.RubyScriptRunner.rubyExec(RubyScriptRunner.java:79)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.DatabaseScriptRunner.execute(DatabaseScriptRunner.java:53)
    at com.greytip.common.scriptrunner.CriticalUpdatesRunner.afterPropertiesSet(CriticalUpdatesRunner.java:30)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
```

Seems like I have struck the jar hell and the maximum allowed characters in stackoverflow. I have removed parts of stacktraces to keeps the characters in range.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that something has been serializing `WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource` objects.

Looking at the source code, it is not declaring an explicit serialVersionId field, so the version id is being generated on the fly based on the classes fields and so on.

Apparently, changes to the C3PO implementation mean that the generated has changed.

So ... if these objects are serialized with the old classes and deserialized with the new classes ... or vice versa ... the result will be this exception.

What is the solution?

1. You need to make sure that your systems are using the same version of C3PO everywhere.
2. If these serialized `WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource` (I guess "bindings") have been persisted (e.g. stored in files) by your JNDI registry, you need to remake / refresh them.

I *think* that should be sufficient ...

Comment: I have generated the bindings using the libraries I have in my project. Still I am getting the same error. Does jtds and jndi drivers cause this as I haven't touched them. Since the error is thrown by a class inside c3p0 I am confused as I am now using the same c3p0 jar in project and for binding. Does this have anything to do with tomcat?

Comment: If you have regenerated the bindings, then >somewhere< in your system by must >still< be using two different versions of C3PO.  Could it be something to do with Tomcat?  Possibly.  Have you put an old copy of the C3PO classes into the Tomcat shared libraries?  Either way, you should be able to find all C3PO JAR files ... using `find`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have forgot to move on of the bindings file generated to the patch from where it is being read by the application. I have edited the question with new findings.

Comment: Yes.  That is a different problem.  I suggest you ask a different Question. But it is probably just that you are using incompatible versions of the dependencies.   Remember this is a Question and Answer site ... with one question per Question.